# how to have the md-label showing on a particular position on the html page?

Tags: html, material-design

I want to have a label aligned to a certain position, such as after a space of width "col-cs-3".  My html part:

```
<div class="row someRow">
        <label class="col-xs-3"></label>            
        <md-label class="col-xs-7">
            {{some description text }}
        </md-label>
</div>
```

I want the "some description text" to start after the empty space of col-xs-3, but this code apparently does not do the trick.

Comment: Some CSS for your layout/that custom `md-label` tag would really help answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use  class="col-xs-3" with material design, If you want to align on particular position, you should go for material layout using Flex attribute,

You can find the [`documentation`](https://material.angularjs.org/#/layout/grid) here